# How to acess elements in vector of lists

Tags: c++, vector, hash, linked-list

My assignment is implementing a hash table of strings and I don't understand some parts of it.

In the task, I create a class called set:

```
class set
{

   size_t set_size;           // Total number of elements.

   double max_load_factor;
   std::vector< std::list< std::string >> buckets;

   std::hash< std::string > hash; 
   std::equal_to< std::string > eq;

   ...
```

for table I use vector of lists from STL: **std::vector< std::list< std::string >> buckets**

The main task is the implementation of functions which helps to properly create a hash table of strings and measuring the performance of the program.

The problem I faced is how I don't know how to implement a function simple_insert:

```
bool simp_insert( const std::string& s );
      // Returns true if the insertion took place.
      // simp_insert is called 'simple', because it does not rehash.
```

I don't understand how to find an element in a vector of lists, additionally does [] works in vector, like in an array (**buckets[1]** is equal to **array[1]** )?

```
for( buckets[hash_index] :: iterator it = buckets[hash_index]. begin( ); it != buckets[hash_index]. end( ); ++ it )
{
     if(*it == s){
       return false;
     } 
}
```

Here I want to compare strings and if it is already in list it should return false and whole function stops 
But I am not sure about accuracy of this code

Comment: If you want to search everywhere, then you would loop over the vector, and each element within the list. i.e. `for ( auto &list : buckets ) { for ( auto &str : list ) … }`. That said, the hashing algorithm should tell you which bucket to search in, so you don't have to search each list. And yes, vector elements can be accessed via `operator[]`

Comment: great, thanks now I understand better what should I do!

Comment: so if I want to access 3rd bucket:
```for( buckets[hash_index] :: iterator it = buckets[hash_index]. begin( ); it != buckets[hash_index]. end( ); ++ it )
{
     if(*it == s){
       return false;
     } 
}
```

Comment: `bucket[0]` is first, `bucket[1]` is second, ...

Comment: Oh it's a little bit messy, so I edited Q

Comment: Looks right. Keep in mind that the vector must have a size large enough for all the buckets. So, if you're accessing bucket 3, it must have at least a size of 3. PS: use `auto` instead of `buckets[hash_index]::iterator`

Comment: nice, I almost forgot about this magical `auto`))) thx